# How do I remove the green line in Adobe Media Encoder?

Tags: flash, encoding, video-editing, adobe-media-encoder

I'm trying to resize a Flash video (F4V) and in the media encoder, there is a green line along the left edge of the screen.  This green line is visible in the Adobe Media Encoder, but not in the source video.  This green line is then visible on the output video.  How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your video dimensions are divisible by 4. If not you'll see the green line as the codec tries to interpolate the pixels.